# How to develop a USB mass storage simulator in Linux?

Tags: usb, storage, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am new to programming USB. I want to develop a simulator in Linux for USB mass storage devices. I would be thankful to you if you share links.

Answer (score 2):

You means running as USB target mode?

Check the gadget driver:

- http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html
- http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=USB_Gadget
- http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30/drivers/usb/gadget/file_storage.c

NOTE: this need hardware support

Comment: Hardware support is ability to be in usb host mode (which most PDAs does)

Answer (score 1):

There is also interesting library for using usb gadgets from userspace which might be easier for development:

http://github.com/ueno/libusb-gadget